# What is the difference between Joshua 15:14-19 and Judges 1:12-15

Tags: bible

Joshua is retold **during** his life, whereas Judges is told **post burial**, after his death (Judges 1:1).
However, we see the story repeat itself where Caleb offers his daughter in exchange for conquering land.
Can someone explain, is this a duplicate, or what is happening here?

Comment: This question might be better located on [Stack Exchange - Biblical Hermeneutics.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: What evidence do you have that the book of Joshua was written during Joshua's lifetime ? I am not disputing that it is so, I just think the question requires it as background detail.(The recording of important pieces of evidence is that the two accounts require mention of various details for different reasons, pertinent to the different purposes of the two individual books.)